# How do I *completely* remove a jQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I've got a date text field I wish to only *sometimes* attach a DatePicker to, because I have some of my own text-handling scripts which handle partial date strings.  Calling .remove or .destroy leaves text formatting behavior on the input field, however, which converts my "8" string into a "8/18/2010".  Even worse, if I start deleting, it steadfastly assumes that, once I reach "8/18/20", I *actually* wanted "8/18/2020".

What would be the best way to completely, entirely, make-it-like-it-never-was remove the datepicker from my page?  I can also use it if it just ignores text I enter entirely at all times, though in that case I'd prefer it to appear on a double-click / an image-as-button, not always.

edit:

this is all within a jqGrid, where 'selector' is a text box on a date column:

```
function showPicker(selector) {
    $(selector).datepicker({
        onClose: function() {
            $(selector).datepicker('remove'); 
            // or 'destroy' or $('.datepicker').remove(); or $(this).datepick('remove');
        }
    });
}
```

This prevents it from coming back, but not from manipulating my text field.  No other code (that I'm aware of) is manipulating that field's contents, just jqGrid watching for the enter-key to send the data.  Looking at the page's generated code, the datepicker div is even still at the bottom.

edit2: I get the exact same behavior if I do this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
 $("#pickle").datepicker({
  onClose: function(){
   $(this).datepicker('remove');
  }
 });
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="pickle" />
</body>
</html>
```

That causes identical behavior to what I'm seeing, but changing it to 'destroy' works *here* but not on my page.  Odd.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

This removes `.datepicker` COMPLETELY:

```
$( selector ).datepicker( "destroy" );
$( selector ).removeClass("hasDatepicker").removeAttr('id');
```

Documentation:

 https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy

 also read the comments below

Comment: Why the second line is used for ? Apparently the destroy reinit the input at this initial status

Comment: @eka808 the first line only disables date-picker, but it is still in your DOM. The second line takes care of that.

Comment: I still have a <div id="ui-datepicker-div"> that was not there before calling .datepicker(...) after running this code

Comment: @isak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589900/remove-the-id-attribute-from-a-div-using-jquery `$('#ui-datepicker-div').removeAttr('id');`

Comment: @Isak Another thing you can do is to eliminate that element from the DOM. Be careful with this one!: `$('#ui-datepicker-div').remove();`

Comment: For some reason this solution causes an error in my case: "Uncaught TypeError: dataPicker.destroy is not a function". If you replace the first line with $( selector ).unbind(); it works perfectly

Comment: When I execute the 2nd line, I'm unable to reinit datepicker to the same element.

Comment: @GregoryR. The `removeAttr('id')` is wrong and should be removed, since the id has nothing to do with the datepicker, and if you rely on the `id` you won't be able to set it back.

Comment: @Merlevede same behaviour here. It is not necessary to remove id attribute.

Answer (score 8):

I solved the problem by removing the datepicker classes and then calling the unbind method on the element tied to the datepicker. That seemed to get rid of it!

eg:

```
$('#myelement').datepicker();

/////////datepicker attached to myelement//////
```

and then:

```
$('#myelement').removeClass('calendarclass');
$('#myelement').removeClass('hasDatepicker');
$('#myelement').unbind();
```

Just removing the classes still let the input element invoke the datepicker when clicked in. possibly `unbind()` by itself would do the job, but I'm kind of a belt-and-braces chap.

Comment: @jasonmarcher I think you misspelled `#emyelement` (The last line). Shouldn't it be `#myelement`?

Comment: I didn't, but I will fix it.

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me. I just added $('myelement').removeAttr('id'). thanks!

Comment: I am cloning a datepicker element and this is the only solution that worked for that.

Answer (score 3):

depending on your situation, you could do it server side

**Ex.** in asp-like sytax

```
<% if( showDatePicker ) {%>
    $('#dp-div').DatePicker(); // or whatever
<% } %>
```

**Edit**
How about setting the [dateFormat](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat) of the datepicker? 
ie

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

you might be wanting

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: '...' });
```

Comment: Simple, I must agree.  But this is all client-side, and that would require re-building *anything* containing the picker code, and probably watching for JS data too.  It seems to be tacking onto the rest of the page elsewhere, which is probably what's hanging around after I supposedly remove / destroy it.  Not sure if that'd handle it, unless I refreshed the whole page (too expensive).

Comment: @Groxx so is the idea that you want to be able to let the user type OR use a datepicker? and when the date picker is closed, you want the text to render with your css, not DatePicker's?

Comment: @Lucas: My... css?  Not entirely sure what you mean.  I've edited again, and have found a reduced-case that duplicates my *behavior*, but not apparently my *cause*, if you want to see.

Comment: @Groxx I'm just wasn't sure what behaviour you are seeing. Adding something to answer...

Comment: @Lucas re recent edit: no, that just replaces my text with periods in both pieces of code.  I'd also thought that might work after looking at the documentation, but it appears it's just a demo of the field, not anything useful.  I've also tried 'constrainInput: false', but that's the default and changes nothing :\.

Comment: @Lucas: and today it magically works.  Literally magically, I launched visual studio, hit ctrl-F5, and it's behaving exactly like it should.  As such, I'm going to remove / vote to remove this question, because it can't really help anyone.  Thanks for the help though!  edit: or not.  Bah.  Was hoping to not pollute SO further...

Answer (score 0):

In single page application,
even if the contents of the page change, jquery ui remains garbage.
So I do like this in single page application.

```
(function($) {

    if ($.ui !== null && typeof $.ui !== typeof undefined) {
        /**
         * dialog fix
         */
        var $oDialog = $.fn.dialog
        $.fn.dialog = function(mth, dialogOpts) {
            if (mth !== null && typeof mth === 'string') {
                if (mth === 'clean') {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');   // you must set id
                    if (id !== null && typeof id !== typeof undefined) {
                        // garbage jquery ui elements remove
                        $('[aria-describedby="' + id + '"]', document).each(function() {
                            if ($(this).dialog('instance')) {
                                $(this).dialog('destroy');
                            }
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }
                    return this;
                } else if (mth === 'open' && dialogOpts !== null && typeof dialogOpts === 'object') {
                    if ($oDialog.apply(this, ['instance'])) {
                        $oDialog.apply(this, ['option', dialogOpts]);
                        return $oDialog.apply(this, ['open']);
                    } else {
                        return $oDialog.apply(this, dialogOpts);
                    }
                }
            }

            return $oDialog.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

use like this in page script

```
// target layer in my page
var $xlsDiv = $('#xlsUpFormDiv');

$xlsDiv.dialog('clean');    // clean garbage dialog

var dialogOpts = {
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    height: 800,
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: ...,
    close: function() {
        $xlsForm.reset();
    }
};

// initialize original jquery ui
$xlsDiv.dialog(dialogOpts);

// open button click
$('#btnViewXlsUpForm').on("click", function() {
    $xlsDiv.dialog('open', dialogOpts);
});
```