# How to remove an id attribute from a div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I want to remove the id attribute from this image:

```
<img width="270" class="thumb" id="thumb" height="270" src="img/1_1.jpg" />
```

I tried doing this:

```
$('img#thumb').RemoveAttr('id','none');
```

But it is not removing the ID!

EDIT:

```
$('img#thumb').attr('src', response);
$('img#thumb').attr('id', 'nonthumb');
```

This deosnt load the picture, or in this case the src! But when I remove the id attribute, it works fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888095/
Not working with unwrap

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The capitalization is wrong, and you have an extra argument.

Do this instead:

```
$('img#thumb').removeAttr('id');
```

For future reference, there aren't any jQuery methods that begin with a capital letter. They all take the same form as this one, starting with a lower case, and the first letter of each joined "word" is upper case.

Comment: they all use (lower) camelCase, not PascalCase.

Comment: @getaway read the [api](http://api.jquery.com/) as it'll answer your questions (you're looking for the `attr` function).

Comment: Thanks @zzzzBov. I couldn't remember if it was "camelCase" or "CamelCase".

Comment: @patrick dw that's because both are correct. in programming I use `camelCase` to mean "lower camel case" and `PascalCase` to mean "upper camel case".

Comment: @getaway: Sorry, I didn't notice your first comment there. Thanks to @zzzzBov for answering above.

Comment: its okay, i have another problem, im going to ask another question, becuase i dnt think jquery is doing things in order!!

Comment: @patrick @zzzzbov can you look at the edit!! :)) sorry for bugging you guys

Comment: @getaway: Do you have more than one element on the page with the same ID?

Comment: @getaway: I'm confused by your EDIT. Is that the code that works, or that doesn't work. The `src` and `id` attributes don't affect each other. So I'm not sure the cause of the issue without more info.

Comment: can i show you the full jquery code, http://pastie.org/1427372 , basically the #img src deosnt chnage, when i put the chnage id attribute!

Comment: i just checked firebug, it seems that the id gets chnaged, before the src tries to load in, but obviously it cnt becuase it cnt find the id anymore!! if you get what i mean! deos jquery compile in order!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm really not certain what the issue is. If I may, I'll leave you with a couple pointers. First, always use proper code indentation. It makes it much easier to read and analyze. Second, never do multiple DOM selections in a row. You have `$('img#thumb'+targetid)` several times in a row, which means it needs to go back to the DOM and find that same element over and over again. Inside the `.load()` callback, `this` will refer to the element on which it was originally called, so you can just do `$(this)` to refer to that element. Sorry I couldn't help more with that odd issue. :o(

Comment: @getwaway: Just saw your previous comment. Again, not sure, but keep in mind that AJAX calls are *asynchronous*, so they do not necessarily happen sequentially. Special care needs to be taken in those situations.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure what [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) you're looking at, but you should only have to specify `id`.

```
$('#thumb').removeAttr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove attribute with the following

$("#my_id").prop("id", "");