# Realign HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML like this :

```
"""<input type="submit" id="continue" value="CRA" name="continue" class="keyboard-enabled" tabindex="7">

<a href="#" id="r1A" role="button" tabindex="-1">
    <input type="button" id="r1B" value="Back" role="option" aria-pressed="false" class="keyboard-enabled" tabindex="6">
</a>"""
```

I want to move my first input down to `<a` using jquery replace or something like this in JS. How to achieve this ?

Expected output :

```
<a href="#" id="r1A" role="button" tabindex="-1">
    <input type="button" id="r1B" value="Back" role="option" aria-pressed="false" class="keyboard-enabled" tabindex="6">
</a>
<input type="submit" id="continue" value="CRA" name="continue" class="keyboard-enabled" tabindex="7">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : use `.after()`

```
$(function(){
  $('#r1A').after($('#continue'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked and if i want to remove complete line   "<a href="#" id="r1A" role="button" tabindex="-1">"   and "</a>"

Comment: unwrap() is not a function

Comment: to remove complete line use `$('r1A').remove()`