# remove complete href link tag from html

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get

EXPECTED INPUT :

```
<a href="#" id="r1A" role="button" tabindex="-1">
        <input type="button" id="r1B" value="Back" role="option" aria-pressed="false" class="keyboard-enabled" tabindex="6">
</a>
    <input type="submit" id="continue" value="CRA" name="continue" class="keyboard-enabled" tabindex="7">
```

converted to

```
<input type="button" id="r1B" value="Back" role="option" aria-pressed="false" class="keyboard-enabled" tabindex="6">
```

using JQUERY replace or remove.
Please suggest.

Comment: `$('#r1B').unwrap()`

Comment: Not working.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888095/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.fn.unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

```
$('#r1B').unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about;

```
$('#r1B').parent().replaceWith($('#r1B'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4u63rozo/)