# How Remove the id from the ul tags in the wp_nav_menu() function

Tags: css, menu, html-lists, removeclass, import-from-excel

please help me how to remove id from menu ul in wordpress custom menu.i m not able to remove id from id from ul tag my code is

i want to remove id="menu-primary-menu" 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

For all those searching for a solution:

You can remove the menu_id if you use items_wrap in the template like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
  ...
  'items_wrap' => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  ...
) );
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I removed the class="%2$s" from the items_wrap ul because I didn't want a class/id on it, but I left the %2$s inside the tag, is this okay to do?

Answer (score -1):

add this to functions.php:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', '__return_false');
```

Alternatively with jquery:
[How to remove an id attribute from a div using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589900/how-to-remove-an-id-attribute-from-a-div-using-jquery)

As always, backup first and use child themes.

Comment: thanks for reply i used this filter but my problem is still same please help me i m new in wordpress

Comment: Post your code here, including the menu HTML, CSS, and the functions.php

Comment: Actually this filter removes the id from menu li not the ul