# datepicker : disable days using drop down list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have a drop down list which looks like this :

```
   <span id="billet">
      <select id="test">

          <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
          <option value="Option2">Option2</option>

       </select>
   </span>
```

And an input like this :

```
   <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

By choosing "*option1*", I would like to disable week-ends from datepickers.

By choosing "*option2*", I would like to reactivate all the days from datepickers.

Here is my JS :

```js
$("#billet").on('change', 'select', function() { 
     if($('#test').val() == 'Option1') {
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
       beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
      });
     }
     else {
      $('.datepicker').datepicker();
     }
    });
```

Note : I use "span" to circle my select because this drop down list is created dynamically by Ajax / PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are: should destroy it.

```js
$("#test").change(function() {
  // remove destroy datepicker
  $('.datepicker').datepicker("destroy");
  if ($('#test').val() == 'Option1') {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
    });
  } else {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  }
});
$("#test").trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<span id="billet">
      <select id="test">

          <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
          <option value="Option2">Option2</option>

       </select>
   </span>

<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

Refer: [How do I *completely* remove a jQuery UI datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516995/how-do-i-completely-remove-a-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Again you have to destroy `datepicker` while choosing `option 1` second time

Answer (score 0):

Use This :

```
  $("#billet").on('change', function () {
                if ($('#test').val() == 'Option1') {
                    $('.datepicker').datepicker('option','beforeShowDay', $.datepicker.noWeekends);
                }
                else {
                    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
                }
            });
```

Thanks :)